# How to force Serilog to log only my custom log messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I configured Serilog in `appsettings.json` to log entries into **Logstash** via tcp in my `asp net core web api` app the following way:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Network" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo:0": {
      "Name": "TCPSink",
      "Args": {
        "uri": "tcp://172.26.48.39:5066"
      }
    },
    "Properties": {
      "app_id": "my-service-api",
      "index": "my-app-"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But it logs too many messages. For example, I have a CreateToken action method in Token controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> CreateToken([FromBody] CredentialsModel credentials)
{
    var user = _authentication.Authenticate(credentials);

    if (user == null)
    {
        Log.Warning("Unable to authenticate an user: {Login}, {Password}",
        credentials.Username, credentials.Password);

        return Unauthorized();
    }

    return BuildToken();
}
```

I need to log only one message:

> Unable to authenticate an user Login Password

But Serilog logs the following:

> Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/token
>   application/json 57
>
> Route matched with "{action = \"CreateToken\", controller =
>   \"Token\"}".  Executing action
>   "Deal.WebApi.Controllers.TokenController.CreateToken (Deal.WebApi)"
>
> Executing action method
>   "Deal.WebApi.Controllers.TokenController.CreateToken (Deal.WebApi)"
>   with arguments (["Deal.BL.Models.Auth.CredentialsModel"]) - Validation
>   state: Valid
>
> Unable to authenticate an user: Login Password
>
> Executed action method
>   "Deal.WebApi.Controllers.TokenController.CreateToken (Deal.WebApi)",
>   returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UnauthorizedResult" in
>   11.0935ms.
>
> Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 401
>
> Executed action "Deal.WebApi.Controllers.TokenController.CreateToken
>   (Deal.WebApi)" in 95.272ms
>
> Request finished in 123.9485ms 401

How can I get rid of unwanted messages?

This is my `Program.cs` file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{currentEnv}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Start web host");

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override category-level log messages in your `appsettings.json`. For example, the following `appsettings.json` sets `Microsoft` log messages to only log out for those considered `Error`:

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

The property of interest here is `Override`, which represents an object where the properties are category *prefixes* and the values are the [Serilog log level](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#minimum-level) to use.

Because your own custom log message will not be logged under a `Microsoft` category, you will still see *that* in the output.